# Load multiple URLs using SimpleXML

Tags: php, url, load, simplexml

I'm requesting information from a remote server which is sent back to me as XML, I use SimpleXML to parse it. However I need to load multiple URLs, can I do so through one file, or do I need to have a different file for each request?

My code looks something like this

```
$url = 'http://...';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a loop that deals with the multiple urls...

```
$all_urls = array('http://url1', 'http://url2', 'http://url3');
foreach ($all_urls as $url) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and place '$xml = simplexml_load_file($url)' into it. Then you can call the function from within a LOOP. That's the only way I am able to get it to call simplexml_load_file($url) more than once within a loop.

```
$all_urls = array('url1', 'url2', 'url3');

foreach ($all_urls as $url) {
    importXml($url);
}

function importXml($url){

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

    //Do stuff...
}
```